# Call delegation vs partial function application

Tags: language-agnostic, functional-programming

I need to call a function with two parameters from many places in my code.

```
hash(itemToHash, algorithm) { ... }
```

I don't want to pass the `algorithm` parameter in each of the function calls.

I could create a function with one parameter that would delegate the call:

```
md5hash(itemToHash) {
   hash(itemToHash, 'md5')
}
```

Or I could use partial application to bind the `algorithm` parameter.

The way I would go about this would be to create a higher order function that returns the partially applied hash function and I would call this higher order function from many places in the code to get the single parameter function.

However, isn't that unnecessary complicated? I don't really see any benefit in the second approach compared to simple call delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have some function `partial` that partially applies arguments to other functions. You don't need to call this `partial` function everywhere in your code that want to make use of the partially applied function.

In fact you have to call it only once. To generate a partially applied function and then say, bind it to a name.

```
md5Hash := partialRight(hash, 'md5')
```

As for my understanding even

```
md5Hash(itemToHash) {
    hash(itemToHash, 'md5')
}
```

is some kind of partial application. Albeit a static one. The benefit of a `partial` function is the ability to create partially applied functions at runtime.